# what is the correct way of setting background image of a frame using JLabel?

Tags: java, image, swing, icons

Previously,i was using the following statement for setting the background of a frame

```
  JLabel backImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C\\users\\BSK\\Desktop\\win.png"));
```

and it was working fine and produces the following result.(coding for buttons is not shown)[image]

But when i created new Package named `Resource` and put the image in that and uses following statements

```
JLabel backImage=new JLabel();
ImageIcon img;
img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Resource/win.png"));
backImage.setIcon(img);
```

I get the following result:-

[image]

As you can see my puzzle box goes out of scope.So what is the difference between these two approaches?

**EDIT** Layout for JLabel `backImage` used is Border Layout.i am firstly setting the content pane of the JFrame as the JLabel which is `backImage` and adding the buttons in a separate pannel in GridBagLayout and then adding the pannel to the contentpane of the frame which is again the JLabel `backImage`.

Comment: Can be a relative path problem, try: `img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Resource/win.png"));`

Comment: How is the label added to the frame?  What layout manager is in use?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: @Pphoenix The image is there, it's just WAY over on the right :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes it is there i know but why it is not "there"?

Comment: How is the label been laid out?  Are you adding other components to it? Are you setting it's text properties?

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is BorderLayout for the JLabel and buttons are on a pannel whose layout is GridBag and its opacity is false.

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes i am firstly setting the content pane of the JFrame as the JLabel which is `backImage` and adding the buttons in a pannel in GridBagLayout and then adding the pannel to the contentpane of the frame which is again the JLabel 'backImage'.

Comment: @MadProgrammer take a look now.

Comment: That's not really a runnable example...

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok i am updating the code please wait.

Comment: try using null layout

Answer (score 1):

The location of the `ImageIcon` is determined by the layout manager of the frame's content pane, `BorderLayout` by default. Alternatively, override `paintComponent()` in the button panel. Invoke `drawImage()` on the supplied graphics context to render the image in the desired location and size. Add the button panel to the enclosing frame's content pane.